# How to generate a tags file for all C++ files in the other directory?

Tags: c++, windows, vim, cmd, ctags

For example in **Windows**, I don't want to add the address of the *ctags58\* folder of **Exuberant Ctags** to the *Path* of my *Environment Variables*. The only way to generate a tags file with *(cmd)* Windows Command Processor or Vim *(text editor)* is to set your current directory *(`cd`)* to `ctags58` folder, and then now you can run the `ctags` command.

- How to generate a tags file for all C++ files including *".h"* files in the other directory such as *"C:\Users\USER\Projects\PROJECT\include"* address?
- And also to generate tags file for all C++ files in the other directory and on all subdirectories?

Comment: Consider using Indexer plugin ( http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3221 ), which provides painless automatic tags generation for whole project(s) and keeps tags up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to go to the *ctags* install directory; just invoke it with an absolute path, e.g. `"C:\Program Files\ctags58\ctags.exe"`.

You can also extend the `PATH` just inside Vim (in your `~/.vimrc`), so that you can invoke it from Vim with `:!ctags ...`:

```
:let $PATH .= ';C:\Program Files\ctags58'
```

---

For recursive tag generation, pass `-R` or `--recurse` to `ctags`.

Note that there are a couple of plugins on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/) that make updating the tags database easier for you.